# Can't able to print the failure Message in Jmeter if API request getting fail

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, jmeter, load-testing

I tried the multiple API hits on the server through Jmeter and save the result data in the file but some how I cant print the failure Message in the file, any body helps me how to print the failure message.?[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a JSR223 post processor, where you will need to do a little scripting to get what you need to save as a CSV file.  Here is basic pseudo-code to help with this.

```
//use PREV to get response data from previous sampler
prev.getResponseDataAsString()
//format this data (remove commas) and output to CSV file
outLog.write(csvResponse + "\n")
```

for an example in java, please see:

https://lobsterautomation.wordpress.com/2018/01/14/jsr223-tips-and-tricks-part-5/

Answer (score 0):

`failureMessage` in the .jtl results file is applicable only for [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), if you're looking for a way to create a custom file having only response message and response data the easiest way is going for [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/), the basic configuration would look like:

[image]

You can install Flexible File Writer using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/):

[image]